# Send a this.state to Store from component and retrive from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, setstate

I don´t now what is the best aprove to do this:

I have a from that you can select a currency and depending on the currency you select a Table is redenred this the currency selected.

I am using, REACTJS, REDUX , MDBDataTable from mdbreact and the form is using  Select from antd.

The MDBDataTable is working i am able to send data, the select also is working. The only thing that I need is some way to send información that I selecting the currency based on these information I can buid my data jason to send to my table.

Maybe this is no the correct idea, I open to any sugestion. (I not a programer this i way am asking for help).

[image]

The component code where i am trying to send the value to the sorte (At the end):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class SelecionarCrypto extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
    this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
    this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this);

    console.log("(SelecionarCryto.js):",this.props);

    this.state = {
      ValorState: "nada"
    }


  };

 onChange(value) {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
    this.setState({ValorState: value});
    console.log("(SelecionarCryto.js)  New value onchange", this.state.ValorState)

  }

  onBlur() {
    console.log('blur');
  }

  onFocus() {
    console.log('focus');
  }

  onSearch(val) {
    console.log('search:', val);
  }



render(){


const { Option } = Select;

console.log("(SelecionarCryto.js) New value Render: ", this.state.ValorState)








return (
  <Select
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Seleciona:"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
    onBlur={this.onBlur}
    onSearch={this.onSearch}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
  >
    <Option value="ETH">ETH</Option>
    <Option value="BTC">BTC</Option>
    <Option value="XRP">XRP</Option>
  </Select>

  );
}


  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      token: state.token,

    };
  };

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return{
    ValorState: "pruebasEnviar"
  }
};

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SelecionarCrypto);
```

This part is only an extract where I am tring to extract the value from my STORE.

```
  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      token: state.token,
      ValorState: state.ValorState
    };
  };

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PruebasAPI3);
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having currency state in local state, you need to dispatch an action to redux store to update the currency.

you table component would read the currency state from redux store and render the table accordingly.

Comment: Hi, it´done now but is returning undefined . I the store the value is OK and in action i see how the value is changing.